# Create contracts in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, contract, laravel-5.4

Documentation on `laravel.com` is not sufficient. Can any one guide me through how to How To Create contracts in `Laravel` from scratch.

I need implementation of Contracts in `Laravel`. Right now, I'm using `Laravel 5.4`

Answer (score 4):

[Contract](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/contracts) is just a fancy name for `php interfaces`. We have being using them all along and its not a new thing.

`Contracts/Interfaces` help us to maintain a loosely coupled code base. See the example from doc below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Orders;

class Repository
{
    /**
     * The cache instance.
     */
    protected $cache;

    /**
     * Create a new repository instance.
     *
     * @param  \SomePackage\Cache\Memcached  $cache
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(\SomePackage\Cache\Memcached $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve an Order by ID.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Order
     */
    public function find($id)
    {
        if ($this->cache->has($id))    {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Here when ever the `Repository` instantiate we **should** give a `\SomePackage\Cache\Memcached` instance in order for code to work. Hence our code is tightly coupled with `\SomePackage\Cache\Memcached`. Now look at below code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Orders;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as Cache;

class Repository
{
    /**
     * The cache instance.
     */
    protected $cache;

    /**
     * Create a new repository instance.
     *
     * @param  Cache  $cache
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

Same thing but now we just need to provide **some** cache interface. And behind the scene you could have done something like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Orders;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as Cache;

class RedisCache implements Cache {
     // 
}
```

When above `Repository` instantiate, php will look at the `Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository` and It has been implemented by `RedisCache` class.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid [Gayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994996/7358623) needs further elaboration to hit [Rajan's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41994778/7358623).

Yes Gayan is correct that creating a `Contract` class basically means creating a php `interface`.

Continuing the Cache example above, if we look into its source code (you can find it at [this Github repo file](https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/5.4/Cache/Repository.php)), we can see something like this

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Cache;

use Closure;

interface Repository
{
    /**
     * Determine if an item exists in the cache.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function has($key);

    /**
     * Retrieve an item from the cache by key.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($key, $default = null);

    // the rest...
}
```

If we are using this interface in our laravel app, it is said to be a "Contract". It is declaring what methods/properties a class should have if it implements this interface. For example in our app...

```
<?php

namespace App\Whatever;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository;

class Foo implements Repository {
     // 
}
```

Then class `Foo` will need to have methods `has` and `get` in order to fulfil what has been stated in the `Repository` contract.